# Database Query - Order by two values (Nested Order)

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, database-design, database-schema

I want to order results by two database values: **rating_full** followed by **rating_count**

Currently, Im ordering by the highest **rating_full**. it works fine.

```
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} rating ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = rating.post_id AND rating.meta_key IN ('rating_full'))";
```

…

…

```
$sql = "cast(rating.meta_value as decimal(10,2)) {$order}";
```

……

The first line of code, part of the SELECT statement, retrieves the **rating_full** part

The second line of code is the ORDER BY part, which currently just uses the **rating_count**

As far as I can tell **rating.meta_value** referred to in the second line of code is the **rating_full** value

I'm trying to get it to ORDER BY **rating_full**, **rating_count**
I'm not sure how to modify the first line so that I can achieve this.

Thanks

**FULL CODE:**

```
<?php

// Sorting
add_filter('posts_join', 'directorySortingJoin',10,2);
function directorySortingJoin($join, $query) {
global $wpdb, $aThemeOptions;
if ($query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_admin &&   ((isset($_GET['dir-search'])) || (isset($query->query_vars["a-dir-item-category"])) || (isset($query->query_vars["a-dir-item-location"])))) {
    $sql = "";
    // default ordering
    $orderby = (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->defaultOrderby)) ? $aThemeOptions->directory->defaultOrderby : 'post_date';
    // get from get parameters
    if (!empty($_GET['orderby'])) {
        $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
    }
    if ($orderby == 'rating') {
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} rating ON   ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = rating.post_id AND rating.meta_key IN ('rating_full'))";

        //$sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} rating ON (wp_posts.ID = rating.post_id AND rating.meta_key IN ('rating_full')) LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} count ON ({$wpdb->posts} = count.post_id AND count.meta_key IN ('rating_count'))";


    }
    if ($orderby == 'packages') {
        directorySaveUserPackagesToDb();
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} packages ON ({$wpdb->posts}.post_author = packages.user_id AND packages.meta_key IN ('dir_package'))";
    }
    if (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->showFeaturedItemsFirst)) {
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} featured ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = featured.post_id AND featured.meta_key IN ('dir_featured'))";
    }
    $join .= $sql;
    //echo $join;
}
return $join;

  }
   add_filter('posts_orderby', 'directorySortingOrderby',10,2);
  function directorySortingOrderby($orderby, $query) {
    global $wpdb, $aThemeOptions;
 if ($query->is_main_query() && !$query->is_admin && ((isset($_GET['dir-search'])) || (isset($query->query_vars["a-dir-item-category"])) || (isset($query->query_vars["a-dir-item-location"])))) {
    $sql = "";
    // default ordering
    $orderby = (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->defaultOrderby)) ? $aThemeOptions->directory->defaultOrderby : 'post_date';
    $order = (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->defaultOrder)) ?   $aThemeOptions->directory->defaultOrder : 'DESC';
    // get from get parameters
    if (!empty($_GET['orderby'])) {
        $orderby = $_GET['orderby'];
    }
    if (!empty($_GET['order'])) {
        $order = $_GET['order'];
    }
    if ($orderby == 'rating') {
        if (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->showFeaturedItemsFirst)) {
            $sql = "featured.meta_value DESC, convert(rating.meta_value, decimal) {$order}";
        } else {
            //$sql = "convert(rating.meta_value, decimal)    {$order}";

            $sql = "cast(rating.meta_value as   decimal(10,2)) {$order}";
            //$sql = "cast(rating.meta_value as decimal(10,2)) {$order}, count.meta_value {$order}";

        }
    } else if ($orderby == 'packages') {
        if (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->showFeaturedItemsFirst)) {
            $sql = "featured.meta_value DESC, packages.meta_value {$order}";
        } else {
            $sql = "packages.meta_value {$order}";
        }
    } else {
        if (isset($aThemeOptions->directory->showFeaturedItemsFirst)) {
            $sql = "featured.meta_value DESC, {$wpdb->posts}.{$orderby} {$order}";
        }
    }
    $orderby = $sql;
    //echo $orderby;
}
return $orderby;
}
// Save directory packages for sorting
function directorySaveUserPackagesToDb() {
$users = get_users();
// capabilities list
$roles = array(
    'administrator' => 10,
    'directory_5' => 9,
    'directory_4' => 8,
    'directory_3' => 7,
    'directory_2' => 6,
    'directory_1' => 5,
    'editor' => 4,
    'author' => 3,
    'contributor' => 2,
    'subscriber' => 1
);
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if (isset($user->roles[0])) {
        if (array_key_exists($user->roles[0], $roles)) {
            update_user_meta($user->ID, 'dir_package',    $roles[$user->roles[0]]);
        } else {
            update_user_meta($user->ID, 'dir_package',   0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) for `ORDER BY` should be helpful here, particularly the last paragraph on sorting multiple columns.

Your `ORDER BY` should be something like

`ORDER BY rating_full DESC, rating_count DESC`

Comment: Thanks I was aware of that, sorry maybe I was not clear.

Comment: What is your complete query, then? What problems are you having?

Comment: That's mostly my problem i don't have the complete query. :/

Comment: I meant, you said you're currently only ordering by "rating_full" and the query works. Can you post the query that achieves this?

Comment: Im modifying existing code, i don't have the query. I tired $sql = "cast(rating.meta_value as decimal(10,2)) {$order}"; and it worked for that. But I'm completely lost for Order by rating_count. - I understand i need the query but its confusing

Comment: From looking at the code you have commented out in the `directorySortingJoin` function, it looks like you have some typos when compared to your working code. `//$sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} rating ON (wp_posts.ID = rating.post_id AND rating.meta_key IN ('rating_full')) LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} count ON ({$wpdb->posts} = count.post_id AND count.meta_key IN ('rating_count'))";`
Should the `LEFT JOIN` constraints be `{$wpdb->posts}.ID` , as in your working code? One is `wp_posts.ID` and the other is just `{$wpdb->posts}`. What errors do you see?

Comment: you are actually correct but i don't think it will work.